# Microsoft Visual Studio Code pop out a console window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the Code Runner extension to run my Python code, but I don't want the output be in the Microsoft Studio Code window. I want an independent window to pop out. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open launch.json and change this line to this:

```
        "console": "externalTerminal" // rather than integratedTerminal
```